# Why my cross compiler toolchain not static link?

Tags: gcc, toolchain, cross-compiling, linux-from-scratch, clfs

I want to build my cross compile tool chain, I build it successful.
It can use normally, but when I move it, it cannot work!!

It print `error while loading shared libraries: libcloog-isl.so.3`, `libcloog-isl` is not install in my host.

I configure the gcc with --disable-shared, but when I run ldd to the cc1 in my cross compile tool chain, I found that ppl, gmp, moc, libgcc_s and some other link to my host library. why it cannot static link into cc1 when I use --disable-shared.
I found that Sourcery CodeBench's tool chain can run anywhere, its cc1 not link my host library.

What should I do to static link in cc1 instead of dynamic link host library?

Answer (score 0):

You may already be aware that the ld command (as well as gcc) will accept the **-static** option, but you may also need to use **-static-libgcc** and/or **-static-libstdc++** to make sure you are linking statically to all libraries.